# Find this something and replace what comes after it

Tags: php, jquery

Basically I want PHP to open a config file, search for a string  and replace what comes after
The problem that I have in the code that I have created is that it finds  the string `$db_pass =` and is able to replace it... but then in the file there is an extra  `"password");` line... so i need it to be able to replace the entire line or either cut the rest to be able to delete it.

```
    $dbFile = 'dbconfig.php';
    $String = "\$db_pass =\"new_password\";\n";
    file_put_contents($dbFile, str_replace("\$db_pass =", $String,    file_get_contents($dbFile)));
```

dbconfig.php

```
    <?php
    // Database Constants
    db_pass = "hi";
    db_user = "hssi";
?>
```

my current script outputs like this
dbconfig.php

```
       <?php
    // Database Constants
    db_pass = "new_password";
"hi";
    db_user = "hssi";
?>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?  Have you considered `sed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to replace the whole line, rather than the beginning of the line. [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is the PHP function for find and replacing with regular expressions.

Sample code to do what you're looking for would be:

```
$dbFile = 'dbconfig.php';
$String = '$db_pass = "new_password";';
file_put_contents(
    $dbFile,
    preg_replace('/\$db_pass = "(.*)";/', $String, file_get_contents($dbFile))
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
str_replace("\$db_pass =", $String
```

Use:

```
preg_replace('/\$db_pass = "(.*)";/', $String
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php